# What vue.js hook do I need to use to validate an internal variable on page load?

Tags: vue.js

I want to display an error message if necessary when a page loads. The only way I can get this to work is to call the validation method from outside the Vue instance.

**Is there an internal hook that I could be using instead?**

http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/ahd34a3v

## HTML:

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model="startTime" v-on:keyup="validateTime(startTime)"/>
  <div>
  {{errorMessage}}
  </div>
</div>
```

## JavaScript:

```
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: function() {
        return {
            startTime: 'hello',
      errorMessage: ''
        }
    },
  mounted: function() {
    this.validateTime(startTime);
  },
    methods: {
        validateTime: function(time) {
        this.errorMessage = 'the length is ' + time.length;
        }
    }
});
// vm.validateTime(vm.startTime); //WORKS BUT IS NOT IN AN INTERNAL HOOK
```

Comment: How about `created` ?

Comment: `created` doesn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/edwardtanguay/5c54nwmv

Comment: You forgot to reference correct variable from model (`this`) - http://jsfiddle.net/cvt5maze/
`this.startTime` should be passed.

Comment: ah, thanks, yes, both created and mounted work now, as I thought they should